# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=1-2(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n})+2(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n-1})=1-2\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\frac{1}{2n}+2\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\frac{1}{2n-1}$

I am stuck here. The answer is supposed to be $2\log2-1$

Comment: Just a hint: consider the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$ evaluated at 1 to figure out what some of your terms evaluate to.

Comment: @user293121 Thanks that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By noting
$$\frac{1}{n} = \int^1_0 x^{n - 1} \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{n + 1} = \int^1_0 y^n \, dy,$$
you could always find your sum by first converting it to a double integral. Doing so we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{n(n + 1)} &= - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (-xy)^n \frac{dx}{x} dy\\
&= - \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left [\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-xy)^n \right ] \frac{dx}{x} dy\\
&= -\int_0^1 \int_0^1 -\frac{xy}{1 + xy} \cdot \frac{dx}{x} dy \tag1\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y}{1 + xy} \, dx dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \ln (1 + xy) \Big{|}_0^1 \, dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \ln (1 + y) \, dy\\
&= \big{[}(y + 1) \ln (1 + y) - y \big{]}_0^1,\\
&= 2 \ln (2) - 1,
\end{align*}
as expected.

Notes

(1) The sum is geometric.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n>0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n>0}\left[\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\right]=\sum_{n>0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}+\sum_{n>0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$$then recall that
$$\sum_{n>0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\ln 2$$via the Taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$ with $x=1$. Note, on the second sum you will need to apply an appropriate shift of $n$ to obtain an expression similar to the Taylor series for $\ln(x+1)$ at $x=1$.

Comment: While inspirational, it involves rearranging *conditionally convergent* series. This is a dangerous operation; the rearranged sum often has a different value than the original. You can fix the argument by looking at the partial sums, which involve only finitely many terms.

Comment: Well yes, you could first do the partial fraction decomposition with partial sums, but then eventually you would just take the limit to obtain the series forms (which both converge by the alternating series test).

Answer (score 0):

Write the series in terms of partial fractions as:

$$\begin{align}
a_k &= \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(k)(k+1)} = (-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)\\
a_{k+1} &= (-1)(-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Thus the required sum is equivalent to:

$$\begin{align}
S &= +1-\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{4}...\\
 &= -1+2\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}...\right) \\
 &= -1 + 2\ln(2)
\end{align}$$

where we used the [Series representation of $\ln(2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm_of_2#Series_representations)